# unable to create entity framework database in class library

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.1

I have a class library. within this project I have a folder named 'models' with a few class models. I have all the references I need.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection2" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MDD;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MDD.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

After running `update-database` it throws the following error:

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\MDD.mdf'
>   may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry
>   the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could
>   not be created. Check related errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

the `app.config` does not suppose to have `<connectionStrings>`. the `Web.config` do.
then in the MyDbContext.cs:

```
public MyDbContext():base("connectionString"){}
```